# how to use slim redirect

Tags: php, redirect, slim

I have a problem. I am using slim and I have route for my main page:

```
$app->get('/', function() use ($app) { ...
```

In one of my controllers I want to redirect to the main page, so I write

```
$app->response->redirect('/', 303);
```

But instead of redirection to the '/' route I'm getting redirected to the root of my local server which is `http://localhost/`

What am I doing wrong? How should I use redirect method?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Slim allows you to name routes, and then redirect back to them based upon this name, using `urlFor()`. In your example, change your route to:

```
$app->get('/', function() use ($app) { ... })->name("root");
```

and then your redirection becomes:

```
$app->response->redirect($app->urlFor('root'), 303);
```

See [Route Helpers](http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/helpers/) in the Slim documentation for more information.

Comment: To avoid URL hijacking you should use 307 since HTTP 1.1.

Comment: How do you add a flash message?

Answer (score 24):

From Slim3 docs
http://www.slimframework.com/docs/start/upgrade.html

```
$app->get('/', function ($req, $res, $args) {
  return $res->withStatus(302)->withHeader('Location', 'your-new-uri');
});
```

Comment: It is perfect, and is according to Slim v3.x documentation also worked for me, thanks.

Comment: You can also use `$res->withRedirect('your-new-uri');`

Comment: I am getting `withRedirect ` method not found error in Slim 4, so had to use this answer.

Comment: @sulaimansudirman Same here! Any idea why withRedirect is mssing fo us?

Comment: How do you pass a message along with the response?

Comment: Slim supports a `withBody(..)`, I would try that - https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/response.html#the-response-body

Answer (score 15):

Slim 3

```
$app->get('/', function ($req, $res, $args) {
  $url = 'https://example.org';
  return $res->withRedirect($url);
});
```

Reference: https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/response.html#returning-a-redirect

Comment: Can you please provide a documentation reference/URL of this API?

Comment: @MNR It isn't explicitly mentioned in the documentation, though it is used in the [Cookbook entry regarding trailing slashes](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/cookbook/route-patterns.html). (Here is the [source code](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/Slim/Http/Response.php#L278) for the withRedirect method of the Response object.)

Comment: Reference: https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/response.html#returning-a-redirect

Answer (score 7):

give your '/' route a name,

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/', function () {
       echo "root page";
    })->name('root');


$app->get('/foo', function () use ($app) {
       $app->redirect($app->urlFor('root') );
    });

$app->run();
```

This should give you the correct url to redirect

http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/names/
http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/helpers/#redirect

Answer (score 6):

**Slim 4:**

```
$response->withHeader('Location', '/redirect/to');
```

Or in place of fixed string:

```
use Slim\Routing\RouteContext;

$routeParser = RouteContext::fromRequest($request)->getRouteParser();
$url = $routeParser->urlFor('login');

return $response->withHeader('Location', $url);
```

Slim Documentation: http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/objects/response.html#returning-a-redirect
RouteContext: https://discourse.slimframework.com/t/redirect-to-another-route/3582

Answer (score 5):

```
//Set Default index or home page
$app->get('/', function() use ($app) {
      $app->response->redirect('login.php');
});
```

Comment: How do you add a flash message to the redirect response?

Answer (score 4):

**For Slim v3.x:**

Use `$response->withStatus(302)->withHeader('Location', $url);` instead of `$app->redirect();`

> In Slim v2.x one would use the helper function $app->redirect(); to trigger a redirect request. In Slim v3.x one can do the same with using the Response class like so (see the following example)[1].

Use `pathFor()` instead of `urlFor()`:

> urlFor() has been renamed pathFor() and can be found in the router object.
>   Also, pathFor() is base path aware[2].

Example:

```
$app->get('/', function ( $request, $response, $args ) use ( $app ) {
  $url = $this->router->pathFor('loginRoute');
  return $response->withStatus(302)->withHeader('Location', $url);
});
```

**Note:** additional parameters can be supplied by passing an associative array of parameter names and values as a second argument of `pathFor()` like:  `$this->router->pathFor('viewPost', ['id' => 1]);`.

> The router’s pathFor() method accepts two arguments:
>
> 1. The route name
> 2. Associative array of route pattern placeholders and replacement values[3]

**References:**

1. [Changed Redirect](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/start/upgrade.html#changed-redirect)
2. [urlFor() is now pathFor() in the router](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/start/upgrade.html#urlfor-is-now-pathfor-in-the-router)
3. [Route names](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html#route-names)

Answer (score 0):

I think I faced a similar problem, and the issue was with my **.htaccess** config file. It should actually be something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /api #if your web service is inside a subfolder of your app, 
# you need to pre-append the relative path to that folder, hope this helps you!

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using ./ instead of / will work also.