# Redirect to route with GET parameters

Tags: php, redirect, routes, slim, slim-3

I'd like a route that parses and puts together an array of `GET` parameters to redirect to another route that expects `GET` parameters.

I had hoped this would work, where I pass `$search_params` as part of the `pathFor()` method:

```
// SEARCH VIEW
$app->get('/search', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $api = $this->APIRequest->get($request->getAttribute('path'),$request->getQueryParams());
    $args['data'] = json_decode($api->getBody(), true);
    return $this->view->render($response, 'search.html.twig', $args);
})->setName('search');

// ADVANCED SEARCH VIEW
$app->get('/advanced_search', function ($request, $response, $args) {    
    return $this->view->render($response, 'advanced_search.html.twig', $args);
});

// ADVANCED SEARCH PROCESS
$app->post('/advanced_search', function ($request, $response, $args) {    

    // get settings
    $settings = $this->get('settings');

    // get post parameters
    $qp = $request->getParsedBody();

    // translate advanced search form parameters to Solr-ese
    $search_params = array();
    $search_params['q'] = $qp['query'];

    // redirect to GET:/search, with search parameters
    $url = $this->router->pathFor('search', $search_params);    
    return $response->withStatus(302)->withHeader('Location', $url);

});
```

But this did not append the array `$search_params` as GET parameters.  I understand that if the `/search` route had expected arguments in the URL with something like `{q}` it would get caught, but I need to append an unknown bunch of `GET` parameters.

My workaround is to do the following, manually using `http_build_query()` to append the `GET` parameters as a string to the route URL:

```
// SEARCH VIEW
$app->get('/search', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $api = $this->APIRequest->get($request->getAttribute('path'),$request->getQueryParams());
    $args['data'] = json_decode($api->getBody(), true);
    return $this->view->render($response, 'search.html.twig', $args);
})->setName('search');

// ADVANCED SEARCH VIEW
$app->get('/advanced_search', function ($request, $response, $args) {    
    return $this->view->render($response, 'advanced_search.html.twig', $args);
});

// ADVANCED SEARCH PROCESS
$app->post('/advanced_search', function ($request, $response, $args) {    

    // get settings
    $settings = $this->get('settings');

    // get post parameters
    $qp = $request->getParsedBody();

    // translate advanced search form parameters to Solr-ese
    $search_params = array();
    $search_params['q'] = $qp['query'];

    // redirect to GET:/search, with search parameters
    $url = $this->router->pathFor('search')."?".http_build_query($search_params);    
    return $response->withStatus(302)->withHeader('Location', $url);

});
```

But that feels clunky.  Am I missing something about Slim 3 and redirects?

Is it related to a `POST` route redirecting to a `GET` route?  I tried using the HTTP code `307` for the `withStatus()` in the redirect, but as somewhat expected, that changed the method request going to `/search`, which doesn't work for our purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to add the `q`-param inside the query, the router has 3 parameter:

1. The route name
2. Associative array of route pattern placeholders and replacement values
3. Associative array of query parameters

You are currently adding your `q`-parameter as route placeholder, that would work if you have something like this as route `/search/{q}` so for adding it as query parameter, use the 3rd parameter

```
$url = $this->router->pathFor('search', [], $search_params);
```

Comment: Nailed it.  I hadn't thought of pathFor() pointing to a route "object", with those 3 parameters.  I had thought it was just using that "search" to get the base path and match that way.  But it makes perfect sense, and in fact, it nice that you *can* pass the response object too.  Thanks a million!

Comment: This works great, but is it an undocumented feature? The [User Guide](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/router.html) even says "The router’s pathFor() method accepts two arguments:" and lists exactly what you have for #1 & #2.

Comment: @davidreedernst seems like the user guide is just outdated. The parameter should be there already for ~3 years [Slim/Router.php#L425](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/Slim/Router.php#L425).