# Slim 3 response withRedirect

Tags: php, slim, slim-3

I'm trying out slim responses object and redirect feature, i have routes and controllers like this :

routes :

```
    $app->get('/', 'index:index')->setName('index');
```

in my controller i have this line :

```
    return $response->withRedirect($this->router->pathFor('index'));
```

index function in index class :

```
public function index($request, $response)
{
    return $this->view->render($response, 'index.html', $this->data);
}
```

its working, but it gives a HTML document response instead of redirecting me, is this correct behaviour ? if so, how do i redirect to that route ?

Comment: if you get any error with the solution given below, then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this:

```
$uri = $request->getUri()->withPath($this->router->pathFor('index'));
return $response->withRedirect((string)$uri);
```

You may need to pass `$this->router` to the controller’s constructor.

Comment: it still gives me a raw html document instead of redirecting

Comment: And what the HTML is? is the page which should be rendered after redirection ?

Comment: Here are several solutions which can be helpful to you. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23404355/how-to-use-slim-redirect/38315790)