# Slim Redirect to Website

Tags: php, slim

I have a route and I want to implement a redirection into it.
The root looks like this:

```
$app->get('/registration/validate', function (ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, $args) {

try {
    $user = new \Riecken\PBS\controller\UserController();
    $result = $user->validateRegistration($request);
    $response = $response->withJson($result);
    $response = $response->withStatus(200);
    return $response;
}catch(Exception $e) {

    $response->getBody()->write($e->getMessage());
    return $response->withStatus($e->getCode());

}
```

});

I want to redirect it, just to test it, to google for example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use slim redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23404355/how-to-use-slim-redirect)

Answer (score 0):

In slim, `redirect()` helper used to redirect request to another url. You can use it as:

```
$app->response->redirect('url-here');
```

For more information [visit here](https://docs.slimframework.com/routing/helpers/).